# Tensorflow doing the exact same predictions with completely different hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters

I am having a really annoying problem with my code, using tensorflow. My programm is a simple stock predicting algorithm. My problem is, that whenever I change the hyperparameters of the model (epochs, neurons), the predictions wont change. I get the exact same lines in the plot (for example here the red and blue line are the exact same, although they have completely different neurons and epochs). The predictions only change, if I change the value of batch oder number. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK6TS.png)

I tried to change the hyperparameters of epochs and neurons to get more accurate results. In reality, the predictions didnt change at all. Thats quite strange to me.

Comment: Hi there! Please bring the code to the question. To be helped make stuff simple, nobody will retype code from image. You mentioned graphic. It will be worth to put a link to this graph(s) as you do for the code.